# Display Rig of model in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, collada

does anyone know how (if possible) to display the rig (bones) of a dae model (not the geometry)?
Just like in MAYA, Blender, etc...
We have a model with geometry and rig but we want to hide the geometry and only see the bones.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in Xcode? Maybe this is [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: It’s just easier to visualize the rig.  That’s all. If there is no option it would be nice to have.

Comment: No why are you trying to use Xcode for this? Why not use blender or Maya?

Comment: Just for easy visualization and quick debugging. PLUS what I see in MAYA is NOT what I see in Xcode. .dae files exported from MAYA are meshes up in Xcode.